# class XmlRootAttribute for serialization and deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I would like to create a class that is used for serialization and deserialization. When serializing the attribute name should be "MyNameRequestType" and "MyNameResponseType" when deserializing.

The question is how should i create or override the XmlRootAttribute?

Eg.

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("MyNameRequestType", IsNullable = false)]
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use the [XmlArrayItemAttribute.ElementName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.elementname.aspx) Property . You have to specify an ElementName if you want the name of the generated XML element to differ from the class name.